# Windows 7 taskbar in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, themes

I have been using a theme on Windows XP to make it look like Win 7 but it has some drawbacks like Blue screen dump and shutting down the system.

I want my taskbar and My Computer drive to be just like Windows 7.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm running Vista Drive Icon software to show the drive info. Even I would like to give a MAC look to my XP if there is any setup you know please help me.

Comment: *...some drawbacks like Blue screen dump and shutting down the system.* classic.

Comment: If you're going to theme XP, use Litestep. Nothing quite so cool as working in a start menu and taskbar-less interface.

Comment: Ok thats the better way but how can I see the Drive info like windows 7.......As Vista Drive Icon doesn't show the right info.

Comment: Funny, the first solution that came to my head was upgrade to 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XP has some good theming software available that will let you do this. The best that comes to mind is [WindowBlinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/). Once you have that installed you should be able to download themes from different places like [WinCustomize](http://www.wincustomize.com/).

Comment: I used it but it doesn't so good as ASTON2 check it. It's very cool then windows blind. But i have a problem with it if you will leave your comment then I will share it with you for providing help to me. Thanks.